# How to use CompletableFuture and CompletionStage with exception handling

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I am dealing with some code involving multiple blocking I/O operations to be performed in sequence. The context is a JVM based web application running on Java 8 and Tomcat. I have code that performs three operations in sequence. All are of the blocking nature, and the output of each operation may be utilized in a subsequent operation. Each operation can throw exceptions, either checked or unchecked. I have illustrated with some sample exceptions that can be thrown:

```
String output1 = callToRestAPI(); // throws MalformedUrlException, ConcurrentModificationException

callToDatabase(output1); // throws SQLException, ConcurrentModificationException

boolean output2 = callToSendEmail(output1); // throws MessagingException
```

How would I write this using Java 8's promising (no pun intended) CompletionStage and CompletableFuture?

Comment: How do you handle the exceptions in your current 'pseudo' code?

Comment: I created a custom exception corresponding to each operation, catching any standard Java exception thrown by that operation. Then, a single try block encapsulates all 3 operations, with catch defined for each of those custom exceptions. That way, I know which operation failed.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class HandleException {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)
        .thenApply(__ -> callToRestAPI())
        .thenApply(
            output1 -> {
              callToDatabase(output1);
              return output1;
            })
        .thenAccept(output1 -> callToSendEmail(output1))
        .exceptionally(
            t -> {
              System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + t.getMessage());
              return null;
            });
  }
}
```

thenApply and thenAccept is used when the code is blocking. thenApply is used when we want to return something to next thenXXX method. thenAccept does not return anything.
You can also make callToRestAPI,callToDatabase as Async(non blocking code) using a runAsync or supplyAsync

Comment: Thanks for the example. If I use `supplyAsync`, then would I have to use `thenCompose` so I don&#39;t have to deal with double wrapping of `CompletedFuture`? Also, how would I know which part threw an exception, if I have a single generic exception block at the end? Would I need to inspect the exception using `instanceOf`?

Comment: Yes, if we use thenCompose then we do not have to deal with nested CompletionStage. 
By stack trace, we should be able to make out which part threw an exception. But if we want to show a custom error message based on which part threw an exception then we could use instanceOf.